# How to rectify this Formula Field error

Tags: formula, validation

My Formula field I have the code for below :

```
Integer d = CloseDate.day();
Integer mo = CloseDate.month();
Integer yr =  CloseDate.year();

DateTime DT = DateTime.newInstance(yr, mo, d);
Time Difference (Date/Time) =  Calculating_Date__c  - DT;
```

Here In Opportunity I try to get the date/Time difference in the date field(Close Date) and date/time field(Calculating Date) to display the difference in the result in  date/time field(Time Difference).

But I got this error

> Error: Syntax error. Found 'Integer'

I don't know how to be rectified in this error in here.

So please help me to complete the task. For answer's thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating variables are not allowed in formula fields.
You can directly write

```
DATETIMEVALUE(CloseDate) - Calculating_Date__c
```

Comment: Yes, Maruf Bagwan sir but I have  difference fields date and date/time field

Comment: Here I want the make subtract the date and date time fields and the answer is in the date/time field so that's why I struggle here it makes confusion for me.

Comment: hi, i got your concern, I have updated the answer please check this one

Comment: Oops, I forget 2 datetime difference is alsways number, not date time so thanks for remember me Maruf.And for answer.